# ftp -s:filename login error

Tags: linux, ftp

I'm trying to ftp files from a windows computer to a Linux server (Redhad 6.1 with vsftpd).  I can successfully login from the windows computer using:

```
ftp *servername*
```

and entering my credentials.  However I need to ftp to the server and place a file in a directory because the users in the company will only have control of placing the file needed on the server.  I am using the

```
ftp -s:filename.ftp *servername*
```

command and get an error during the login:
530 Login incorrect.

Login failed.

here is the code in the filename.ftp file:

```
user *username* *password*
sudo cd /dbx2/ekiexport
bi
put myfile.csv
bye
```

I have even tried:

```
user *username* pass *password*
sudo cd /dbx2/ekiexport 
bi
put myfile.csv
bye
```

I know I can just ftp to the server to place the files there myself, but I need the users to run the script when they need to access the file.  That's why I need to use the ftp -s:filename

Comment: are you sure about using `:` in `-s:filename`? I've never seen that on a Linux OR windows cmd line, but your best source of info is help system for `ftp` where the failing client lives. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  I have used:  ftp -s:filename.ftp servername  in the past but it was a few years ago with a different company.

Comment: well `ftp` client are notorious for the range of options, error reporting or lack there-of, etc. So don't assume because it worked one place that it will work in another unless you're using the same "brand" of `ftp` client. Good luck.